# using 802.1x with nic teaming

Tags: cisco, network, ieee-802.1ax, radius, ieee-802.1x

I am working on a project which is mandatory to have each pc configured with two network interface cards as a nic team.
I want to use 802.1x for authentication with a radius server like cisco ISE.
My Question is how nic teaming will work with dot1x regarding authentication and authorization?

Comment: Possibly the answer was given in https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27980/can-i-use-802-1x-and-lacp-to-secure-the-networking-infrastructure   in a nutshell: That won't work.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

LACP and 802.1X don't mix. Unless there are vendor-specific extensions allowing that(?) you can't use them simultaneously on a port.

Link aggregation is normally used between switches or towards hosts/servers. You don't usually and shouldn't use 802.1X port authentication on those links anyway.

You use port authentication when you can't trust ports exposed in some office or other public space. Switches and servers are usually placed in locked rooms or cabinets and not exposed to unauthorized manipulation.